# IO vs referential transparency

Tags: haskell, referential-transparency

Sorry newb question here, but how does Haskell know not to apply referential transparency to e.g. `readLn` or when `putStrLn`-ing a same string twice? Is it because `IO` is involved? IOW, will not the compiler apply referential transparency to functions returning `IO`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IO type is defined as:

```
newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
```

Notice is very similar to the State Monad where the state is *the state of the real world*, so imho you can think of IO as referentially transparent and pure, what's impure is the Haskell runtime (interpreter) that runs your IO actions (the algebra).

Take a look at the Haskell wiki, it explains IO in greater detail: [IO Inside](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside)

Comment: Thinking of the `IO` monad in this way is a terrible way to think about it, and this particular view is an implementation detail of GHC and requires hacks in the compiler to work correctly. To see how terrible this is consider what concurrency would look like in this model. Depending on how seriously you take it, you find that it either provides absolutely no explanatory power or it devolves into metaphysics. Continuation-based or free monad based models are much clearer and more accurate. For this question though what `IO` actually is isn't relevant, just that it's a data type like any other.

Answer (score 15):

You need to distinguish between *evaluation* and *execution*.

If you *evaluate* 2 + 7, the result is 9. If you replace one expression that evaluates to 9 with another, different expression that also evaluates to 9, then the meaning of the program has not changed. This is what referential transparency guarantees. We could common up several shared expressions that reduce to 9, or duplicate a shared expression into multiple copies, and the meaning of the program does not change. (Performance might, but not the end result.)

If you *evaluate* `readLn`, it evaluates to an I/O command object. You can imagine it as being a data structure that describes what I/O operation(s) you want performed. But the object itself is just data. If you evaluate `readLn` twice, it returns the same I/O command object twice. You can merge several copies into one; you can split one copy into several. It doesn't change the meaning of the program.

Now if you want to *execute* the I/O action, that's a different thing. Clearly, I/O operations need to be executed in exactly the way the program specifies, without being randomly duplicated or rearranged. But that's OK, because it's not the Haskell expression evaluation engine that does that. You can pretend that the Haskell runtime runs `main`, which builds a giant I/O command object representing the entire program. The Haskell runtime then reads this data structure and executes the I/O operations it requests, in the order specified. (Not actually how it works, but a useful mental model.)

Ordinarily you don't need to bother thinking about this strict separation between *evaluating* `readLn` to get an I/O command object and then *executing* the resulting I/O command object to get a result. But strictly that's notionally what it does.

(You may also have heard that I/O "forms a monad". That's merely a fancy way of saying that there's a particular set of operators for changing I/O command objects together into bigger I/O command objects. It's not central to understanding the separation between evaluate and execute.)

Answer (score 2):

Due to return values are wrapped into `IO`, you can't reuse them unless you "pull" them out, effectively running the IO action:

```
readLn :: IO String

twoLines = readLn ++ readLn -- can't do this, because (++) works on String's, not IO String's

twoLines' = do
  l1 <- readLn
  l2 <- readLn -- "pulling" out of readLn causes console input to be read again
  return (l1 ++ l2) -- so l1 and l2 have different values, and this works
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.  You’ve probably heard that `IO`  is a monad, which means a value wrapped in it has to use monadic operations, such as bind (`>>=`), sequential composition (`>>`) and `return`.  So, you could write a greeting program like this:

```
prompt :: IO String
prompt = putStrLn "Who are you?" >>
         getLine >>=
         \name ->
           return $ "Hello, " ++ name ++ "!"

main :: IO ()
main = prompt >>=
       putStrLn
```

You’re more likely to see this with the equivalent `do` notation, which is just another way of writing  the exact same program.  In this case, though, I think the unsugared version makes it clearer that the computation is a series of statements chained together with `>>` and `>>=`, where we use `>>` when we want to throw out the result of the previous step, and `>>=` when we want to pass a result to the next function in the chain.  If we need to give that result a name, we can capture it as a parameter, like in the lambda expression `\name ->` inside `prompt`.  If we need to lift a simple `String` into an `IO String`, we use `return`.

The equivalent in `do` notation, by the way, is:

```
prompt :: IO String
prompt = do
  putStrLn "Who are you?"
  name <- getLine
  return $ "Hello, " ++ name ++ "!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  message <- prompt
  putStrLn message
```

So how does it know that `main`, which returns nothing, is not referentially transparent, and that `prompt`, which returns an `IO String`, is not either?  There is something special to `IO`, or at least something `IO` lacks: with many other monads, such as `State` and `Maybe`, there is a way to do a lazy computation inside the monad and discard the wrapper, getting a pure value back out.  You can declare a `State Int` monad, `do` deterministic, sequential, stateful computations inside it for a while, then use `evalState` to get the pure `Int` result back.  You can do a `Maybe Char` computation, like searching for a character in a string, check that it worked, and if so, read the pure `Char` back out.

With `IO`, you cannot do this.  If you have an `IO String`, all you can do with it is bind it to an `IO` function that takes a `String` argument, such as `PutStrLn`, or pass it to a function that takes an `IO String` argument.  If you call `prompt` a second time, it won’t silently give you the same result; it will actually run again.  If you tell it to pause for a few milliseconds, it won’t lazily wait until you need some return value later in the program to do that.  If it returns an empty value like `IO ()`, the compiler will not optimize it by just returning that constant.

The way this works internally is to wrap the object together with a state-of-the-world parameter that is different for each call.  That means that two different calls to `getLine` depend on different states of the world, and the return value of `main` requires computing the final state of the world, which depends on all previous `IO` operations.